# Prevent SAGA in QGIS 3.0 from creating certain outputs?

Tags: qgis, lidar, performance, saga, slope

I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent SAGA from generating temporary files. For example, if I just want to generate a slope map using SAGA I have to wait for all 11 other grids to get processed. Is there a variable I can set or enter that would prevent them from even being created?

The only option we seem to be given is to not add them, but that doesn't prevent having to wait for them to process. I'm processing huge LIDAR raster files, so it would be great to avoid all this unnecessary wait time.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Should be possible to do if you feel like hacking your qgis install.

- look for this file in your qgis install: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/description/Slope%2CAspect%2CCurvature.txt
- you need to change the lines corresponding to all the optional outputs. From http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.3/ta_morphometry_0.html this is everything from the General Curvature line down
- add `|None|True` to the end of these lines (which means default value is none (unset), and the parameter is optional)
- relaunch QGIS

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/6939

Comment: Thanks Nyall, I also tried passing "None" through the dialog box and I think it works that way too because the Python log shows they weren't created either. Going to keep testing and will try this hack to see if there's any change in processing time.

Answer (score 3):

At least in the GRASS version of this algorithm, there is a **Skip Output** option in the **...** button next to each output.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is an option in my Grass tool too but not Saga. I'll see if I can make GRASS work. Unfortunately, SAGA likes grids made with SAGA modules. I was getting errors using slope calculated with the default slope but not SAGA. Thanks!