# How can I adopt updated qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\saga\description txt files?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, saga, parameters

I have one question:

**How can I adopt updated qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\saga\description txt files?**

The rest of this text is "enough detail to identify an adequate answer". I will try to follow the rules and not make any of it look like another question.

I'm running QGIS 3.0.3 in Windows 10. Ran into a bug:

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19205

SAGA -> Terrain Analysis - Profiles -> Cross profiles gets a float where an integer is required

This is like:
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18870, but a different SAGA module.

Looks like NUM_PROFILE is different from the other parameters, but QGIS is sending floats for all three:
Usage: saga_cmd ta_profiles 3 [-DEM ] [-LINES ] [-PROFILES ] [-DIST_LINE ] [-DIST_PROFILE ] [-NUM_PROFILE ]

-NUM_PROFILE: Profile Samples
Integer
Minimum: 3
Default: 10

**The bug is supposedly fixed already, by editing the file:
https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/repository/changes/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/description/CrossProfiles.txt?rev=master**

[File fixed: 
8323462f 06/16/2018 07:35 AM    Nyall Dawson [processing][saga] Fix definition of cross profiles alg, add test]

I downloaded the new txt file and replaced my bad one, with QGIS not running. Started it back up and it still gets the error.

This seems to say replacing the txt files should work:
[Prevent SAGA in QGIS 3.0 from creating certain outputs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281976/prevent-saga-in-qgis-3-0-from-creating-certain-outputs?rq=1)

**How can I adopt updated qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\saga\description txt files?**

*These are not additional questions, they are suggestions of what might be required: 
Perhaps there is some other way to grab QGIS bug fixes immediately? 
Perhaps some txt files get compiled into the ta_profiles.dll or affect other files I need to update?
Perhaps the only solution is to download a full "nightly" build of QGIS? (My internet is very slow and very expensive, so I'd really like to avoid that!)*

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: That process should work. I'd do a full scan of your drive to make sure there's no other copies of the CrossProfiles.txt file anywhere else

Comment: Thank you @ndawson for making me wonder if QGIS really could be using my renamed old file. I learn something every day...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can replace description.txt files with updated or locally edited versions. But you must not rename the original file and leave it in the \description directory - at least in Windows 10. My system repeatedly loaded "CrossProfiles (original, bad).txt" in preference to the new "CrossProfiles.txt" file! I've renamed revised files like that since CP/M was state of the art, and have never seen an OS do that.

With the renamed old file completely removed from its path, QGIS successfully uses the new version.